# Refactor->Rename broken in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I'm using Visual Studio SP1 (Ver 10.0.40219.1) and I created an ASP.NET MVC 3 app.  I'm trying to rename an abstract class that inherits from Controller.

I right-clicked the class name and selected Refactor->Rename.  I changed the name and clicked OK (with Preview reference changes checked).  On the Preview Changes dialog I clicked Apply, and got the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
> Parameter name: startIndex

An ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I too have this problem. Sad to see nobody has an answer yet, maybe this bump will attract someone who knows.